# Simpler expression for $\boldsymbol{C}=((\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{B})^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}^\top)^\top$

Tags: matrices

Is there a simpler way to express the matrix $\boldsymbol{C}$ in terms of matrices $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ if 
$\boldsymbol{C}=((\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{B})^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}^\mathrm{T})^\mathrm{T}$ or $\boldsymbol{C}=\boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{B})^{-1})^\mathrm{T}$?

Similarly, is there a simpler way to express the matrix $\boldsymbol{Z}$ in terms of matrices $\boldsymbol{W}$, $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}$ if

$\boldsymbol{Z}=(((\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{W}^\mathrm{T})^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{Y}^\mathrm{T})$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\mathbf{C} 
&=((\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^\mathbf{T})^\mathbf{T}\\
&=\mathbf{A} \left((\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{B})^{-1}\right)^\mathbf{T}\\
&=\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{I}^\mathbf{T}-\mathbf{B}^\mathbf{T})^{-1}\\
&=\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{B}^\mathbf{T})^{-1}\\
\end{align}

Perhaps this is of some use; I doubt there's much more you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I realized my question was slightly wrong. I've updated it with an additional related question, closer to the one I'm actually interested in.